# How to sort array numbers using Array.Sort

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I've got a fair idea on how it works, I've seen other examples on how to use it just can't figure out how to apply it to my code.

```
using System;

namespace ArrayRandomNumbers
{
    class RandomNumbers
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int[] num = new int[1000];
            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {        
                num[i] = rnd.Next(1000);

                Console.WriteLine(num[i]);
                Array.Sort(num); //Doesn't do anything here
                //Console.WriteLine(num[i] = rnd.Next(1000));
            }          
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does nothing at all happen? Are you outputting the values after you sort them, or using breakpoints to look at the array?

Comment: You can not expect sorted array while it is being constructed!! see answer given by @ekad

Comment: The way I was trying to do it was sort it before it's printed, don't know why I got a negative for that?

Comment: @Carl Blance In that case You should use a printing for loop after the first for loop, see my answer below.

Comment: Carl Blance` I have tried something a bit different using an anonymous method looping across the array which I have called .ToList() this way I could do the `foreach` even quicker against the collection and the sorting is done last and done very quickly, also if you are not familiar with `Random numbers` read up if you are wanting number to be sorted from 1 to 1000 then there is no need for a sort you could just perform a simple loop

Comment: `Carl Blance` I fixed the problem I will edit my answer and you will see what it is that you were wanting to see

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Array.Sort(num);` actually does the sorting for each iteration, but it's inefficient because you only need to sort the array once instead of 1000 times. You need to put `Array.Sort(num);` outside of the `for` loop and create another `for` loop to print the sorted array.

```
int[] num = new int[1000];
Random rnd = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{        
    num[i] = rnd.Next(1000);

    Console.WriteLine(num[i]);
    //Console.WriteLine(num[i] = rnd.Next(1000));
}          

Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to sort the array");
Console.ReadLine();

// sort the array
Array.Sort(num);

// print the sorted array
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{        
    Console.WriteLine(num[i]);
}          

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I think this is right. If you are sorting after every iteration, you are changing the array. There's no guarantee that the x values you already put in will stay in the first x places in the array (here they definitely won't, because they are 0s and what you are putting in is >=0).

Comment: It does work but after it's sorted, sorted value start's at the 700's and end at (998 always) but thank you @ekad. I'll continue to work on it.

Comment: @CarlBlance well the numbers are random, so they could be any integer between 0 and 1000.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this all in one like your original code you could do the following as well 
using System;

```
namespace ArrayRandomNumbers
{
    class RandomNumbers
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int[] num = new int[1000];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            var randList = new List<int>();
            var distinctList = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                num[i] = rnd.Next(1000);
                randList.Add(num[i]);
                Console.WriteLine(randList[i]);
            }
            distinctList = randList.Distinct().ToList();
            distinctList.Sort();
            Console.ReadLine();

            distinctList.ForEach(delegate(int s)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
            });
            Console.ReadLine(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Yields the following output reading left to right, a short snippet based on the random numbers generated when I ran this if you write these numbers to a file you will see that the distinctList will have the sorted values as you have expected I am showing the unsorted results use the code and you can see for yourself in the debugger when you inspect at the last `Console.ReadLine();`

**774
452
566
682
814
702
585
371
469
694
241
168
235
763
35
548
158
212
106
297
921
65
280
419
682
42
116
52
212
523
467
777
195
999
316
836
735
742
6
332
647
645
245
622
674
925
692
141
643
84
85
806
663
476
971
709
171
146
999
772
585
532
159
946
227
464
972
235
447
199
813
416
206
773
650
275
819
657
745
757
350
974
409
128
437
661
113
719
28
606
664
588
742
234
747
114
485
299
395
209
953
457
694
443
270
668
599
890
826
695
889
514
401
242
421
610
123
31
508
565
350
253
206
840
535
224
673
971
26
535
789
520
262
535
803
892
280
965
857
769
61
223
892
332
717
149
187
500
812
136
990
454
790
829
858
700
250
854
908
46
995
628
864
291
906
369
251
865
438
529
330
158
173
739
504
127
360
874
122
385
37
173
158
889
544
334
730
433
677
103
641
425
57
810
773
432
358
600
426
348
898
321
61
283
806
832
280
50
324
731
339
376
731
522
9
821
469
974
746
571
638
818
188
334
887
904
100
362
965
71
768
760
448
774
487
715
112
875
83
712
54
679
108
945
764
265
694
534
801
952
963
384
854
854
709
79
133
726
395
901
731
917
84
252
962
579
928
956
35
294
709
594
891
34
517
958
709
242
570
622
209
566
561
13
108
384
905
593
65
407
581
385
479
181
980
136
595
855
983***

Comment: Is that caused by the way I've written it? I'm trying to do it like 1 , 5 , 44, 77 675, 789, 976. Not start from a high number such as 600* or 700 then + 1 till 998

Comment: you need to understand random numbers depending how someone runs it their numbers will be different..

Answer (score 0):

just for hint to @Carl

Code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        var num = new int[1000];
        var rnd = new Random();

        Console.WriteLine("Before Sorting...");
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            num[i] = rnd.Next(1000);

            Console.WriteLine(num[i]);
             //Doesn't do anything here
            //Console.WriteLine(num[i] = rnd.Next(1000));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("After Sorting...");
        Array.Sort(num);

        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(num[i]);
            //Doesn't do anything here
            //Console.WriteLine(num[i] = rnd.Next(1000));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Process is:
1) make an array, Print it while making (optionally you can sort it too, but it will be inefficient, i  guess.)
2) sort the array.
3) Print out Sorted array.

What you are doing:
1) Make and array.
2) Populate each element with random number.
3) Printing that random number.
4) sorting the array so far made.

hence the Disaster, you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

**Use below Code :**

```
int[] intArray = new int[] {1, 9, 6, 7, 5, 9};

// Sort array in ascending order
Array.Sort(intArray);
Console.WriteLine("Ascending: ");
foreach(int value in intArray)
{
  Console.Write(value + " ");
}

// Reverse array
Array.Reverse(intArray);
Console.WriteLine("\n\nDescending: ");
foreach(int value in intArray)
{
   Console.Write(value + " ");
}
```

**Output:**

```
Ascending: 
1 2 3 4 5 7 9

Descending: 
9 7 5 4 3 2 1
```